# How to Install SQL Server 2008 R2 from the Command

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation, command-prompt

I need install SQL Server engine by command prompt in Windows XP SP3, I find several examples but there aren't any that works fine. I don't have experiance in this type of instalations.

In some the examples that I watched talks about log files that show the errors in the installation, but I don't know where is this file.

¿Can any help me?

Answer (score 0):

In this post explain very well how to Install SQL Server Express R2 in the command prompt:

http://deployit.org/wordpress/script-bits/unattended-sql-server-2008-r2-express/